# Plotly Python Chord Diagram

Tags: python, plotly

I found an example of a Python Chord Diagram [here](https://plot.ly/python/filled-chord-diagram/). Now I would like to customize it furhter in order to show the outer labels and the tickmarks. Is it possible?

[This is an example](http://sites.dartmouth.edu/learninganalytics/files/2016/04/SingleCrsContentAccess2.png) of how the end result should look like:

[image]

So I managed to build the chart, the only things that are missing are the information from the outer area. And I don`t know where in the code I can change that.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this stackoverflow page: [Circular Chord Diagram in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65344303/circular-chord-diagram-in-python/73985381#73985381) where it is shown how to easily create a Chord chart in d3js using Python using the [D3Blocks library](https://d3blocks.github.io/d3blocks/).