# Circular Chord Diagram in Python

Tags: python, chord-diagram

[image]

I would like to create a circular [chord diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_diagram)

I found this link of [chord diagram in plotly v3](https://plotly.com/python/v3/filled-chord-diagram/), but in version4 this seams to be not available.

Same for [chord diagram in bokeh](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.12.0/docs/gallery/chord_chart.html) the new version does not contain a way to create a chord diagram.

How to create a chord diagram with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Chord of holoviews](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Chord.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts, dim
from bokeh.sampledata.les_mis import data

hv.extension('bokeh')
hv.output(size=200)
links = pd.DataFrame(data['links'])
print(links.head(3))
hv.Chord(links)
```

Comment: How do you display such a 3dgraph in a notebook?

Answer (score 3):

With the [D3Blocks library](https://d3blocks.github.io/d3blocks/pages/html/Chord.html) you can create Chord chart in d3js.

```
# Install
pip install d3blocks

# Load d3blocks
from d3blocks import D3Blocks

# Initialize
d3 = D3Blocks()

# Load example data
df = d3.import_example('energy')

# Plot
d3.chord(df)

# Or specify the output path
d3.chord(df, filepath='c:/temp/chord.html')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Erdogant, I tried that example and got a file not found error:
`[d3blocks] >INFO> File not found: [file:////var/folders/sq/x6ltmdb54k12dqb29xfz7xxw0000gn/T/d3blocks/chord.html]`

Also, I notice the labels on your chart diagram don't match the `stormofswords` data. Your labels are from the `energy` dataset, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: The default writing dir is temp. However, maybe it has to do something with system rights or a full disk (?) You can try to set the writing path to something else. I updated the example.